# What is the benefit of RDP 8.0 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have just updated to RDP 8.0 on my three computers with Windows 7 (Office & Home).
Someone said it will not take any advantage of RemoteFX without Windows Server 2008 Hyper-V.

Is there any performance boost with RDP 8.0 on Win 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link that details everything you need to know, but in a nutshell if you aren't connecting to Server 2008 R2 or Server 2012 you aren't gaining much.

> [Enabling a great WAN user experience for Windows 7 SP1 virtual desktops](https://web.archive.org/web/20160103231243/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/rds/archive/2012/10/09/remote-desktop-protocol-8-0-update-for-windows-7-sp1-enabling-a-great-wan-user-experience-for-windows-7-sp1-virtual-desktops.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but i wonder why it has to be. As i know Hyper-V is a "VirtualPC,VMWare" virtualization on Server 2008. It's very strange a server admin create a VM and install a 3D Game or play HD video on HOST and let windows 7 clients to enjoy it.

Comment: It's not necessarily only for games. There are plenty of programs that require 3D acceleration like AutoCAD, Maya, etc.

Comment: Please quote the relevant parts of links you post or say the same in your own words. Outbound links frequently rot and go away, leaving this answer useless.

Comment: I would strongly disagree. We use RD in an enterprise environment without a terminal server. Users go directly through the firewall with a VPN client directly to their workstions. The reported speed increase with RD 8 has been amazing.

Answer (score 3):

In fact RDP8 for Windows 7 improve (a lot) RDP connection if both host and client use RDP 8.

For example: RDP on Gigabit LAN allow full screen 1080p video with audio with a great playback quality, you can definitively remotely use software like Adobe After Effect with minimal impact on performance.

RDP8 on WAN: allow better use of photo, motion graphic, video or 3D software because of the compression of image and the use of UDP to maximize image bandwidth.

RDP8 also have better result than RDP 7.x on multi-screen session.

Finally, if you nest RDP communication (open RDP client from a computer remote controlled from another computer using RDP), RDP8 is performing a lot better.

Unfortunately RDP8 (host features) is not available on Windows 2008 R2.

RDP8 need configuration on Win7 to enable both use of TCP and UDP and enable compression and to take advantage of all benefits of this new protocol more info at:

[AutoCAD, Revit and Microsoft RDP 8.0 (Remote Desktop Protocol)](http://www.thecadmasters.com/wordpress/index.php/2013/01/03/autocad-revit-and-microsoft-remote-desktop-protocol-rdp-8-0/)